# How can I convert a range of cells to text?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that strips away an ID and then copies just the values.

```
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],FIND(""."",RC[1])-1)"
Range("F2:F4448").Formula = Range("F2").Formula
Range("F2:F4448").Value = Range("F2:F4448").Value
```

But the resulting column contains some IDs that start with a letter, and some that do not. I need them all the be treated as a string for a lookup later, but I can't figure out how to do this. After I copy the cells, only the IDs that start with a letter end up working in the lookup. A9999 would work while 9999 wouldn't.

I've tried:

```
For Each i In Range("F2:F4448")
    i = CStr(i)
Next I
```

But that still didn't work.

Comment: Why not convert the lookup value to a string in the lookup formula?

Comment: Because I am using it in more than 1 lookup, so it seems simpler to fix the format of the ID rather than include a text conversion in every lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using:

```
Range("F2:F4448").Formula = Range("F2").Formula
Range("F2:F4448").Value = Range("F2:F4448").Value
Range("F2:F4448").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, "format as text" drives me nuts everytime. Glad it works for you!